# Securing devel grails application with single htpasswd like password

Tags: security, grails, .htpasswd, basic-authentication

I am showing a grails app to some colleagues on a public domain. So far I am working in devel mode and have not deployed via war.

I need to secure the application in order to keep onybody from checking it out / playing with it. I have a user mgmt in place already, but before sb sees anything I would like to have .htpasswd-like protection. If possible, I do not want to enlarge the application itself with plugins (e.g., shiro).

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use HTTP authentication.  HTTP authentication is dead simple to implement, but it's not very secure or usable.  You're better off using shiro or spring-security for a real solution.  That said, a simple filter can check for an HTTP Authorization header and return 401 status code if not present.  That will force the browser to pop up a username/password box, and resubmit the form with the username and password encoded in the headers.

Grails filters must have a class name that ends with "Filters" and go in the grails-app/conf directory. Here's an example:

```
class SimpleAuthFilters {
    def USERNAME = "foo"
    def PASSWORD = "bar"

    static filters = {
        httpAuth(uri:"/**") {
            before = {
                def authHeader = request.getHeader('Authorization')
                if (authHeader) {
                    def usernamePassword = new String(authHeader.split(' ')[1].decodeBase64())
                    if (usernamePassword == "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD") {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                response.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'basic realm="myRealm"')
                response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I am aware of the level of security - and sure this will keep people from simply remembering the URL and testing ...

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to $CATALINA_HOME/*conf/tomcat-users.xml* and restart Tomcat:

```
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="user1" password="password1" roles="role1"/>
```

At your Grails project root, execute `grails install-templates`. This will place *src/templates/war/web.xml* into the project.
(In case the file's not visible in your IDE, this might be a bug. Then find it in the file system.)

[Add the following](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3669/bncbk?a=view) to *web.xml* (as a child of the `web-app` tag) :

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>
      Entire Application
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>role1</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Restricted Area</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: This answer makes assumptions that he's using tomcat, and I get the feeling he's not since he's not using a war and hasn't mentioned anything about running `grails dev run-app` with tomcat. However, I find this answer useful for myself, and have done the same thing when using wars in tomcat, so +1.

Comment: Exactly right, Rob! Like the solution though, might switch once I setup the app "for real".